# Name for new tag for questions on dealing with emotions (discouragement, guilt, jealousy)?

Tags: discussion, tags

Academia inspires a whole range of emotions in people. We get a lot of questions here of the form "How to deal with feeling X?", or "Is it common for people in my situation to feel X?", where X is:

- **Lack of motivation**: [How to stay motivated in a low-motivated group?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24372/how-to-stay-motivated-in-a-low-motivated-group) and [How to motivate myself to do more than the bare minimum that is required of me?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20839/how-to-motivate-myself-to-do-more-than-the-bare-minimum-that-is-required-of-me)
- **Discouraged**:  [How should I deal with discouragement as a graduate student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2219/how-should-i-deal-with-discouragement-as-a-graduate-student) and [How should I deal with discouragement looking at others success?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15457/how-should-i-deal-with-discouragement-looking-at-others-success)
- **Guilt**: [How to stop feeling guilty about the unfinished work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17988/how-to-stop-feeling-guilty-about-the-unfinished-work)
- **Burnout**: [What can I do to recover from a short term burnout?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7668/what-can-i-do-to-recover-from-a-short-term-burnout) and [Strategies to overcome “academic-apathy” in the final stages of the PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10969/strategies-to-overcome-academic-apathy-in-the-final-stages-of-the-phd)
- **Intimidated**: [How do I stop feeling intimidated by my advisor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26615/how-do-i-stop-feeling-intimidated-by-my-advisor)
- **Dread**: [Is it normal to feel dread before starting a faculty position?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21345/is-it-normal-to-feel-dread-before-starting-a-faculty-position)
- **Impatient**: [Is it normal to feel impatient in lectures when a lecturer explains material that could be obtained from textbooks?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12829/is-it-normal-to-feel-impatient-in-lectures-when-a-lecturer-explains-material-tha)
- **Undeserving**: [“I've somehow convinced everyone that I'm actually good at this” - how to effectively deal with Imposter Syndrome](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/ive-somehow-convinced-everyone-that-im-actually-good-at-this-how-to-effect)

I think we need a tag to cover questions specifically about "dealing with the things I am feeling."

The scope of the tag would be something like:

> On emotional issues such as guilt, discouragement, jealousy, or feelings of inadequacy affecting academics and researchers.

It's similar to tags like [health-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-issues), [religious-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religious-issues), and [legal-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-issues) in that scope.

But, I have no idea what such a tag should be called.

I think [emotional-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-issues) implies *abnormal* emotions, which is definitely not something I want this tag name to convey.

And I don't like just [emotions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotions), because then it's likely to also be used for questions about research/study related to emotions. (I know this because that's what happened to [healthcare](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare) before I split it into [medicine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) and [health-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-issues), and there were similar issues with [law](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) until I created [legal-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-issues).) This would make it a bad dual-purpose tag.

Any ideas?

Note: The tag should exclude questions on dealing with *other* people who have these emotions (or, who the OP thinks have these emotions) - these are better categorized as [interpersonal-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpersonal-issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best possible alternative I can think of is [emotional-responses](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-responses).

Answer (score 1):

If one were inclined to poetry, I would suggest [the-gauntlet](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-gauntlet) or [leaky-pipeline](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaky-pipeline), but I suspect those wouldn't be considered appropriate.

More seriously, perhaps [emotional-challenges](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-challenges), implying that these are difficulties, but normal ones that can be overcome.